# How do I plot multiple surfaces in Manipulate?

Tags: plotting, manipulate

I'm trying to make an animation of the conic sections as a variable (`a`) goes from 0 to 2:

```
    Cone[a_] := 
    ContourPlot3D[
    x^2 + y^2 == z^2, {x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 10}, {z, -10, 10}];
    Plane[a_] := Plot3D[z = a*x + 2, {x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 10}];
    InterM[a_] := 
    ParametricPlot3D[{t, -Sqrt[(a^2 - 1)*t^2 + 4*a*t + 4], 
    1*t + 2}, {t, -10, 10}, PlotStyle -> Thickness[0.02]];
    InterP[a_] := 
    ParametricPlot3D[{t, Sqrt[(a^2 - 1)*t^2 + 4*a*t + 4], 
    a*t + 2}, {t, -10, 10}, PlotStyle -> Thickness[0.02]];

    Manipulate[
       Show[
            {Cone[a], Plane[a], InterM[a], InterP[a]}
                                                    ], {a, 0, 2}]
```

Comment: `Cone[]` is a built in function. IT is generally advised to use lower case letters for user created functions.

Comment: You should get error messages when you run your code. Please include that information in your questions. The error message also tells you what it wrong. With Feyre's fix, the code seems to work perfectly fine.

Comment: Why do you define `Cone` to have the formal argument `a`, when it doesn't depend on it?. The cone in your demonstration should just be a static object, not something returned by a function.

Answer (score 1):

As I said in my comment, you don't need or want to represent the cone by a function; a static object will do. Also, there is an error in you definition of `IterM`. With these problems corrected, your `Manipulate` expression works.

```
Plane[a_] := Plot3D[a*x + 2, {x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 10}]

InterM[a_] :=
  ParametricPlot3D[
    {t, -Sqrt[(a^2 - 1)*t^2 + 4*a*t + 4], a*t + 2}, {t, -10, 10},
    PlotStyle -> Thickness[0.02]]

InterP[a_] :=
  ParametricPlot3D[
    {t, Sqrt[(a^2 - 1)*t^2 + 4*a*t + 4], a*t + 2}, {t, -10, 10},
    PlotStyle -> Thickness[0.02]]

Manipulate[
  Show[
    {ContourPlot3D[x^2 + y^2 == z^2, {x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 10}, {z, -10, 10}], 
     Plane[a], InterM[a], InterP[a]}],
  {a, 0, 2}]
```

[image: conics]

Answer (score 0):

Just replace *Cone* by *cone* and it will work -- see @Feyre's comment.

[image: Mathematica graphics]